# Passing props to dynamic react component

Tags: reactjs, dynamic, components

So I have the below code to load a custom component called foo. Loading of the component works fine, but props arent passing to it like I would prefer

```
Container component

....
const id= foo
React.createElement(LoadComponent(id, attributes))
...

Custom component

export const LoadComponent = (id, attributes) => {
    /*This will load up foo.js*/
    const Component = require(`./${id}`);

    return Component;
};
```

How do I pass attributes prop to the Component in this case? I keep getting render exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/zrw7x1zrrp

`props` are being passed to the component as the second parameter of `createElement`

```
const id = "foo";
const LoadComponent = props => {
  return props.id;
};

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(LoadComponent, { id }, null),
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

> React.createElement(component, props, ...children)

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit confusing what you are trying to do. If you are using JSX you shouldn't need to invoke `React.createElement`.

If you insist of doing it without JSX though, `React.createElement` can take 3 parameters as per [React's API](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html). So, in your case your code will be `React.createElement(LoadComponent, { id, attributes }, null)` where the third parameter is the children.

Now, the `id` and `attributes` are accessible from within the `props` object of your custom component. So you have two options:

1. [Destructure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) the props object:

   ```
   export const LoadComponent = ({ id, attributes }) => {
       /*This will load up foo.js*/
       const Component = require(`./${id}`);

       return Component;
   };
   ```
2. Use the props object directly:

   ```
   export const LoadComponent = (props) => {
       /*This will load up foo.js*/
       const Component = require(`./${props.id}`);

       return Component;
   };
   ```